# Change datatype of a column in a spark RDD to date and query on it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

By default when I am loading the data, every column is being considered as a string type. The data looks like:

```
firstName,lastName,age,doj
dileep,gog,21,2016-01-01
avishek,ganguly,21,2016-01-02
shreyas,t,20,2016-01-03
```

After updating the schema of the `RDD` it looks like

```
temp.printSchema
|-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
|-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
|-- age: string (nullable = true)
|-- doj: date (nullable = true)
```

Registered a temporary table and queried on it

```
temp.registerTempTable("temptable");
 val temp1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from temptable")
 temp1.show()
+---------+--------+---+----------+
|firstName|lastName|age|       doj|
+---------+--------+---+----------+
|   dileep|     gog| 21|2016-01-01|
|  avishek| ganguly| 21|2016-01-02|
|  shreyas|       t| 20|2016-01-03|
+---------+--------+---+----------+
 val temp2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from temptable where doj > cast('2016-01-02' as date)")
```

But when I am trying to see the result it is giving me:

```
temp2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [firstName: string, lastName: string, age: string, doj: date]
```

when I do

```
temp2.show()
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: How exactly are you "updating the schema"?

Comment: var x= tempSchema.toArray;val y=StructField("dob",DateType,true);x.update(3,y)
  tempSchema= StructType(x);val temp = sqlContext.applySchema(tempSchemaRDD, tempSchema);

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried your code and it works for me. I suspect the problem is in how you change the schema initially, which looks off to me (granted is a little hard to read when you post it in a comment - you should update the question with the code instead).

Anyway, I have done it this way:

First simulating your input:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("dileep","gog","21","2016-01-01"), ("avishek","ganguly","21","2016-01-02"), ("shreyas","t","20","2016-01-03"))).toDF("firstName", "lastName", "age", "doj")
```

Then:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val temp = df.withColumn("doj", to_date('doj))
temp.registerTempTable("temptable");
val temp2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from temptable where doj > cast('2016-01-02' as date)")
```

Doing the a `temp2.show()` reveals as expected:

```scala
+---------+--------+---+----------+
|firstName|lastName|age|       doj|
+---------+--------+---+----------+
|  shreyas|       t| 20|2016-01-03|
+---------+--------+---+----------+
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion will update my question with complete code and explanation